# css min-width to have a page like facebook

Tags: css

what do I have to put in my css to have that my site works like facebook for example. When you're in facebbok and you resize the window of your browser, the size of the contents remains the same and there is the scrollbar on the bottom.  I've used percentage to set widths but I don't like very much the output.

my css is this.

```
#html {

height:100%;
overflow: scroll;
}

#body {
min-width: 1024px;
height: 100%;
}

#container {
margin-top: 0px;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}
#bloccoCentrale {
margin-top: 0px;
margin-left: 5%;
margin-right: 5%;
min-width: 80%;
height: 100%;
}

#centro {
margin-bottom: 10px;
min-height:930px;
}
```

the page is composed like this image.
http://img846.imageshack.us/img846/109/immaginejjr.png
thanks. I know that is lot confusing!!!

***EDIT***
with my css this is what happens when I resize the window!
http://img850.imageshack.us/img850/2197/cattura2wq.png

Comment: so now what is the question ?

Comment: what I have to add to have a bottom scrolbar? I already have it but  the content of the page shrinks

Comment: If you want to use the exact width styles that facebook has, just open the page and look into the source. If you mean your question generally, then you have no question. In your own CSS the min-width for the body is already set to a px-value. That means if the viewport gets smaller than that you will get a scrollbar.

Comment: Now that I've added overflow:scroll yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to make a `100% width` container, and trying for a fluid layout, use @media queries for specific screen resolutions..it's called responsive designing

Say for example

```
@media all and (max-width: 1000px) and (min-width: 600px) {
  /*Style goes here*/
}
```

You can target specific screen resolutions by defining styles in related resolution media queries, [here's](http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/) a good reference article to get started with `CSS @media queries`

Comment: It is because if you use width as 100% than margins and padding add extra space around your container, learn CSS box model you'll get it what am trying to tell you

Answer (score 0):

If your content is wider than your window you will get a horizontal scrollbar.

Try this:

```
#body {
    width: 150%;
}
```

OR

```
#body { 
    width: 4000px;
}
```

Comment: Seriously?? `width: 4000px?`

Comment: like this the content is too wide!

Comment: @Mr.Alien looks like he is targeting 100inch monitor...lol

Comment: @Mr.Alien Why not? You will get a horizontal scrollbar on most screens...

Comment: @NullPointer haha that's what I thought, btw dude meet me on chat

Comment: @Mr.Alien are you on php chat .?? or anywhere else ?

Comment: now I've added the overflow: scroll; to the body and it works. the point now is that content go out of the page with heigth.

Comment: @NullPointer http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20254/general-chat

Comment: sorry i am guilty that i cant read your mind ....so kindly provide html with your css ....